# Pass twig to controller function in altorouter

Tags: php, twig, altorouter

I have the following:

```
<?php

    require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

    $router = new AltoRouter();

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem( array( 'views', 'views/pages', 'views/partial' ) );
    $twig   = new Twig_Environment( $loader, array(
        'cache'       => 'tmp',
        'debug'       => true,
        'auto_reload' => true
    ) );

    function handleRoutes($name) {
        echo $twig->render($name . '.twig');
    }

    $router->map( 'GET', '/[*:id]', function ($id) {
        handleRoutes($id, $twig);
    });

    $match = $router->match();

    if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
        call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
    } else {
        // no route was matched
        header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
    }

?>
```

The handleRoutes function is *supposed to* take the route name (such as "about" or "contact") and pass it to the twig renderer. However, $twig isn't available in the handleRoutes function and I don't know to how to pass it the object correctly. I tried:

```
function handleRoutes($name, $obj) {
    echo $obj->render($name . '.twig');
}

$router->map( 'GET', '/[*:id]', function ($id) {
    handleRoutes($id, $twig);
});
```

But then then $twig is also not available to the function in $router->map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass variables towards `closures` with the function [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165) e.g.

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/[*:id]', function ($id) use ($twig) {
    handleRoutes($id, $twig);
});
```